# PHP Extract Similar Parts from Multiple Strings

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to extract the parts which are similar from multiple strings.

The purpose of this is an attempt to extract the title of a book from multiple OCRings of the title page.

This applies to only the beginning of the string, the ends of the strings don't need to be trimmed and can stay as they are.

For example, my strings might be:

```
$title[0]='the history of the internet, expanded and revised';
$title[1]='the history of the internet';
$title[2]='published by xyz publisher the historv of the internot, expanded and';
$title[3]='history of the internet';
```

So basically I would want to trim each string so that it starts at the most probable starting point. Considering that there may be OCR errors (e.g. "historv", "internot") I thought it might be best to take the number of characters from each word, which would give me an array for each string (so a multi-dimensional array) with a the length of each word. This can then be used to find running matches and trim the beginnings of the string to the most likely.

The strings should be cut to:

```
$title[0]='the history of the internet, expanded and revised';
$title[1]='the history of the internet';
$title[2]='the historv of the internot, expanded and';
$title[3]='XXX history of the internet';
```

So I need to be able to recognize that "history of the internet" (7 2 3 8) is the run which matches all strings, and that the preceding "the" is most probably correct seeing as it occurs in >50% of the strings, and therefore the beginning of each string is trimmed to "the" and a placeholder of the same length is added onto the string missing "the".

So far I have got:

```
function CompareSimilarStrings($array)
    {
    $n=count($array);

    // Get length of each word in each string >
    for($run=0; $run<$n; $run++)
        {
        $temp=explode(' ',$array[$run]);
        foreach($temp as $key => $val)
         $len[$run][$key]=strlen($val);
        }

    for($run=0; $run<$n; $run++)
        {

        }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm stuck on finding the running matches.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't it possible that the OCR misses a short word or thinks a letter is a symbol? These "running matches" don't seem applicable with this possibility.

Comment: It doesn't miss words, it will often get a letter wrong, but that's why I'm thinking to use the number of letters in each word. Sometimes it will add or remove a letter, but the script would still match those strings which are OK.

Comment: I also want to ask: why is the title not "the history of the internet, expanded and"? It matches well with 50% of the samples, and a large subset matches with the remaining cases. Is there some guarantee that each sample contains the complete title? That is the only clear rule that I can think of that would invalidate this answer.

Comment: True, but I only want the beginning cut with this script. Then I have another algorithm for combining them into one string, which takes the endings into consideration.

Comment: I see. So why does a run of words matter at all if you are only caring about the most likely beginning? This should only call for considering one word at a time, left to right. If we looked at 'published' first, we'd find it isn't very popular. By the time we work to 'the', we find that it is very popular and 'history' is less so. Therefore, we are going to pick 'the'. Then, your other algorithm is going to worry about endings. You'll likely notice that if the real title was "History of the published Internet" then this algorithm would conclude incorrectly, but by what metric?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8152/discussion-between-erisco-and-alasdair)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into [Smith-Waterman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Waterman_algorithm) for local string alignment. It is a dynamic programming algorithm which finds parts of the string which are similar in that they have low [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

So if you want to try it out, here is a [php implementation of the algorithm](http://code.google.com/p/bioguid/source/browse/trunk/biostor/swa.php).